# Enhance(/manipulate) a few popular android app's text(/visual) outputs! (examples: whatsapp, gmail, facebook, ...)

Tags: android

Think you ideally needed to mark up or censor a list of keywords in visual output systemwide, yet cant require to root devices.

That still works on websites through browser plugins.

But is it any thinkable to mess with popular apps like whatsapp, facebook, (one at a time) ?

1. Reading:   I know it is possible to read/change some text inputs yet not generally/all?   http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html
2. A universal way for markup *could* be determining screen coordinate positions of contents by OCR and set transparent overlays on the fly + algined smooth with scrolling, just not convinced how well this can both work and be battery efficient (we could cope with low accuracy in text recognition)

I'm adding all my reputation as a bounty. 
Laying out a good way for any one popular app (top 20 social apps) qualifies as an accepted answer!

Laying out solution for "1." only but for two or more apps also qualifies.

Showing specifically why/where it will work with one app but not with another  also qualifies as an accepted answer.

Comment: have you heard of [Xposed modules](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed).You  mentioned no root. But this is the only way you can do this.  
Modifying things like colors and themes is possible via RRO/LAyers etc.But the text modification that you want would go against the android design

Comment: You could do this at a ROM level by modifying the Implementation of the actual text view.(that can also be done via xposed framework),but this would require root or a custom built ROM

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the visual output of an app. The closest thing you can do to accomplish this is like what Facebook Messenger and LastPass use, which is a feature that allows them to draw over the top of other apps, and LastPass specifically can also read the contents of another app via accessibility permissions. However, that just allows them to draw over the existing apps, and in the case of LastPass, fill out text into input fields. Even with the above options, I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: thanks,  i split the goal in two parts.  "1." reading is the more important one/requirement to continue.  
If "2." doesnt work out at all then overlay like Facebookmessenger at a fixed position will be enough.   

Yet i seriously try both and would add much higher bounty if i had.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Each app on the Android runs in its own sandboxed environment. You can only communicate through Intents with other applications. So unless they're listening for bad Intents(which I hope they're not), you can't really do anything to those applications.